# How does MySQL interpret VARCHAR field size?

Tags: mysql

Suppose a field is declared thusly:

```
a VARCHAR(255)
```

How many characters can be stored in it, is it 255 or 256? And how much space is used?

Should we use a power of 2 and then subtract 1, or it doesn’t matter?

Answer (score 3):

A `VARCHAR(255)` can store up to 255 characters, regardless of the number of bytes per character required by the character set encoding.

The storage requirement is the length of the actual data stored (not the maximum), plus 1 or 2 bytes to store the length of the data -- 1 byte is used unless the maximum possible length in bytes > 255... so a `VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4` uses 2 bytes to store the length, while a `VARCHAR(255) COLLATE ascii_general_ci` uses 1 byte to store the length.  Either column can store not more than 255 characters.

Declare the column size as appropriate for the data being stored.  Using 255 is common, but usually a red flag of sloppy design, since it's rare that this particular value meaningfully represents the maximum appropriate length of a column.

By contrast, a `CHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4` always consumes 255 × 4 (the maximum possible) bytes per column per row, and 0 bytes to store the length, since the stored length does not vary.  These columns are rarely appropriate, except when the column is always a known length and the character set is single-byte, such as a UUID, which would be `CHAR(36) COLLATE ascii_general_ci`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `varchar(255)` would use `255 bytes` (maximum) to store the data and `1 byte` to store metadata (length information) about that data. Essentially, it would be `2^8`. Now, how many characters can you store in `255 bytes` depends on what character set you are using.

*The number of bytes do you need to address & store a character depends upon how many characters does the character set have in total.*

Comment: This is entirely incorrect.  VARCHAR is a character (string) data type, so the length specifies the maximum number of *characters*, **not** the maximum number of *bytes*.  A VARCHAR(255) using utf8mb4 can store up to 255 × 4 bytes but not more than 255 characters, regardless of encoded byte length.  The length is stored as 2 bytes, since the total number of possible bytes > 255 and only the actual length of the stored data is used in memory and on disk. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was talking about the maximum number of characters, because the question was asked like that.